# If array exists in array - multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have two multidimensional arrays. I want to check each item in array 1 and see if it's in array 2 and vice versa.

For example:

```
$arr1 = [
    [
        id => '1',
        order => '123238'
    ],
    [
        id => '2',
        order => '33278'
    ],
    [
        id => '3',
        order => '8892372'
    ]
];

$arr2 = [
    [
        id => '1',
        order => '349483'
    ],
    [
        id => '2',
        order => '9837283'
    ],
    [
        id => '3',
        order => '33278'
    ]
];
```

I want to check by `order`.

So something like this:

```
if($arr1['order'] does not exist in $arr2['order']) {
    echo 'abc';
}

if($arr2['order'] does not exist in $arr1['order']) {
    echo 'xyz';
}
```

I've thought about doing `foreach` loop for both but it won't let me know `arr` # it's missing from.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use in_array() function it should work for you.

Comment: One approach would be: map both arrays to their order and then use `array_diff`to compute the difference between both.

Comment: Will ```in_array``` work if the id is different?

Comment: Also, as a heads up, you should not use assumed strings as your array indices.

Comment: You should probably add some quotation marks to `id` and `order` where you define the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach like this by using `array_column` and `array_intersect_key`

```
 $arr1 = array_column($arr1, null , 'order');
 $arr2 = array_column($arr2, null , 'order');
 print_r(array_intersect_key($arr1,$arr2));
```

Example :- https://3v4l.org/Imbao

Comment: How do you get the ones that are in `arr1` but not in `arr2` and vice versa?

Comment: Yes this works but check this out: https://3v4l.org/dWvMo. `arr2` is not associative array anymore. How can I compare now?

Comment: @TimmyBalk check this out for more details : https://3v4l.org/nTtpL

Comment: Okay thank you but what about this? https://3v4l.org/dWvMo How can I make that work? The `$arr2` is just regular array, not associative array. I just need that to work

Comment: @TimmyBalk in the second case you can use like this https://3v4l.org/f2Ga5, https://3v4l.org/hRvm8

Comment: Also why do you use `array_combine` on `arr2` and `arr2`? Why do you combine the same array?

Comment: @TimmyBalk `array_combine` to make it keys => values

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`array_uintersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) or [`array_udiff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) to find the values in each array that are either the same or different based on the value of the `order` key:

```
// values in both $arr1 and $arr2
print_r(array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function ($a, $b) { return $a['order'] - $b['order']; }));
// values in $arr1 but not $arr2
print_r(array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, function ($a, $b) { return $a['order'] - $b['order']; }));
// values in $arr2 but not $arr1
print_r(array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, function ($a, $b) { return $a['order'] - $b['order']; }));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [order] => 33278
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order] => 123238
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [order] => 8892372
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order] => 123238
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [order] => 8892372
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/e1BKS)

Comment: Thank you but it would it be possible to show the `id` column too?

Comment: @TimmyBalk sure - but if the `id` value is different even though the `order` value is the same should that still be counted as the same value?

Comment: It should be counted as different values but still show both. Also what is this called in programming?

Comment: So just to be clear, for your sample data there would be *no* matching values between `$arr1` and `$arr2`?

Comment: So ID is auto incremented which is something i can't change but there will be matching values of `order` in `arr1` and `arr2`. So if `id` value is different even though `order` value is the same, it should not be treated as the same value

Comment: @TimmyBalk apologies for the radio silence... had to sleep. Based on the answer you accepted I think this might be a simpler method of achieving your desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
      for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
            if (!in_array($arr1[$i]['order'], $arr2[$j])) {
                  echo "abc ";
            }
      }
}
```

It basically checks if each `order` of `arr1` already exists in `$arr2` and if it doesn't exist there, you get one `abc` as output.

Therefore you'd get this as output:

```
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

Here's also a version with a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $arrone){
      foreach ($arr2 as $arrtwo) {
            if (!in_array($arrone['order'], $arrtwo)) {
                  echo "abc ";
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to do this with `foreach` too right?

Comment: Probably. Gimmie a sec I'll try doing it

Comment: @TimmyBalk I edited my answer, now there's one with `foreach` too

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your ids, build a list of order numbers from your second array, then loop through your initial array to check if the order number is not contained within:

Data:

```
$arr1 = [
    [
        id => '1',
        order => '123238'
    ],
    [
        id => '2',
        order => '33278'
    ],
    [
        id => '3',
        order => '8892372'
    ]
];

$arr2 = [
    [
        id => '1',
        order => '349483'
    ],
    [
        id => '2',
        order => '9837283'
    ],
    [
        id => '3',
        order => '33278'
    ]
];
```

Method:

```
foreach($arr2 as $item)
    $orders2[] = $item['order'];

foreach($arr1 as $item)
    if(!in_array($item['order'], $orders2))
        echo $item['order'], " order number is not contained\n";
```

Output:

```
123238 order number is not contained
8892372 order number is not contained
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [array_uintersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) with a custom callback function to check for the value or `order` to get all the intersections.

```
$intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['order'], $b['order']);
});

print_r($intersect);

$notInArr1 = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a["order"] === $b["order"]) return -1;
    if ($a["order"] > $b["order"]) return 1;
    return 0;
});

print_r($notInArr1);

$notInArr2 = array_uintersect($arr2, $arr1, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a["order"] === $b["order"]) return -1;
    if ($a["order"] > $b["order"]) return 1;
    return 0;
});

print_r($notInArr2);
```

[php demo](https://3v4l.org/BWZEK)

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [order] => 33278
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order] => 123238
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [order] => 8892372
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order] => 349483
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [order] => 9837283
        )

)
```